# CollectHsMetrics base coverage output has overlapping targets

Tags: coverage, picard

I am trying to get base coverage information, and am using the `--PER_BASE_COVERAGE` output from Picard tools to get a text file of base level coverage. However, some of my targets are being grouped together. In the targets file, these are separated by one base as such:

```
12      12258595        12258695        +       TARGET1
12      12258696        12258795        +       TARGET2
12      12258796        12259791        +       TARGET3
```

However, when I look at my covg file, I see the following:

```
chr    pos    target   covg 
12  12258595        TARGET1|TARGET2|TARGET3 510
```

Why would HSmetrics group these targets together, and how can I separate them?

Comment: Question is also asked on [biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/365812/).

Comment: Hello @Blaze9, I don't understand your question. Would you maybe explain bit what are the targets? Are they read groups? (disclaimer, I am not a Picard tools user); I usually use samtools for this.

Comment: Hi @KamilSJaron, the targets are either tiling regions or exons/introns. I can checkout samtools to see if it provides better results. The per_target_coverage output does not combine the targets which is the weird part. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I see. Maybe you want to [edit] your question and add as many details as you can (such those you wrote in the comment) :-).